# Sending requests with Facebook for Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using the facebook sdk 3.0.1 for Android. I've followed the tutorial and the app works fine. the only problem is that nobody received my request even if my app says that the requests were succesfully sent. this is my code:

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {



    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    RequestsDialogBuilder requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,Session.getActiveSession(),params));
    requestsDialog.setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Network Error", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                         Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request sent",  
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Request cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }   
                }

            })

   .build().show();
}'
```

Comment: What do you mean by no one received the request? Do you mean they can't see the post on your wall?

Comment: App requests go to app center (and not as a notification). Are you checking app center, or are you expecting something in their notifications tray?

Comment: This function should send a request in my friend's notification tray, but nobody receive it. I've got another function that post a message on my wall and it works fine. It is necessary to have the app page in the app center correctly configure or it doesn't matter for this?